# JAXB Marshall a Map structure of generic type

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb

Following this example (http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html) of Blaise Doughan that works, i am trying to generalize it to any type using generics.
I obtained :

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyMapType<K, V> {

    public List<MyMapEntryType<K, V>> entry;

    public MyMapType() {
        entry = new ArrayList<MyMapEntryType<K, V>>();
    }

}
```

and ,

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class MyMapEntryType<K, V> {

    @XmlAttribute
    public K key;

    @XmlValue
    public V value;

}
```

then,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public final class MyMapAdapter<K, V> extends
        XmlAdapter<MyMapType<K, V>, Map<K, V>> {

    @Override
    public MyMapType<K, V> marshal(Map<K, V> arg0) throws Exception {
        MyMapType<K, V> myMapType = new MyMapType<K, V>();
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : arg0.entrySet()) {
            MyMapEntryType<K, V> myMapEntryType = new MyMapEntryType<K, V>();
            myMapEntryType.key = entry.getKey();
            myMapEntryType.value = entry.getValue();
            myMapType.entry.add(myMapEntryType);
        }
        return myMapType;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<K, V> unmarshal(MyMapType<K, V> arg0) throws Exception {
        HashMap<K, V> hashMap = new HashMap<K, V>();
        for (MyMapEntryType<K, V> myEntryType : arg0.entry) {
            hashMap.put(myEntryType.key, myEntryType.value);
        }
        return hashMap;
    }

}
```

finally,

```
package forum832656;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo<K, V> {

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyMapAdapter.class)
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<K, V> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Then i tried this,

```
 Foo<Integer,String> f = new Foo<Integer,String>();
    f.getMap().put(1, "HELLO");
    f.getMap().put(2, "WORLD");


    JAXBContext context =   JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class,MyMapType.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(f, System.out);
```

But i obtained a NullPointerException on JAXBContext creation line....
Any idea?

Comment: Could you show us the stack trace of the NullPointerException?

Comment: My final goal is to Marshall a Map<Date, Map<String,AnotherClass>> ...

Comment: In order to find out why you get an NPE when trying to create a JAXBContext, we need to see the stack trace (with line numbers and exception messages) that you're getting as a result of this.

Comment: @G_H, it works now. I added XmlElement annotation to MyMapEntryType and an empty constructor. It is OK for simple cases but failed when i try a Nested structure such as Map<Date,Map<String,AnotherClass>  i am still getting an exception on that Nested Map structure ...

Comment: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
     - with linked exception:
     [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.HashMap nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
 at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with a recursive Adapter:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MapAdapter<K, V> extends XmlAdapter<Adapter<K, V>, Map<K, V>> {

    @Override
    public Map<K, V> unmarshal(Adapter<K, V> v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
        for (MyEntry<K, V> mapEntryType : v.getEntries()) {
            map.put(rUnmarshal(mapEntryType.getKey()),     rUnmarshal(mapEntryType.getValue()));
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter<K, V> marshal(Map<K, V> v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Adapter<K, V>(v);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> T rUnmarshal(T obj) throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Adapter) {
            return (T) new MapAdapter<>().unmarshal((Adapter<Object, Object>) obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> T rMarshal(T obj) throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Map) {
            return (T) new MapAdapter<>().marshal((Map<Object, Object>) obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @XmlType
    @XmlRootElement
    public final static class Adapter<K, V> {

        @XmlElement
        protected List<MyEntry<K, V>> fEntries = new LinkedList<MyEntry<K, V>>();

        // needed for JAXB
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Adapter() {
        }

        public Adapter(Map<K, V> original) throws Exception {
            for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : original.entrySet()) {
                this.fEntries.add(new MyEntry<K, V>(entry));
            }
        }

        public List<MyEntry<K, V>> getEntries() {
            return this.fEntries;
        }

    }

    @XmlType
    @XmlRootElement
    public final static class MyEntry<K, V> {

        @XmlElement
        protected K fKey;

        @XmlElement
        protected V fValue;

        // needed for JAXB
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private MyEntry() {
        }

        public MyEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> original) throws Exception {
            this.fKey = rMarshal(original.getKey());
            this.fValue = rMarshal(original.getValue());
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return this.fKey;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return this.fValue;
        }

    }

}
```

This should avoid your NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Above code did not compile here, I had to modify it to the code below. I don't like the large amounts of xsi: and xlmns: stuff in the serialized form though.

```
package misc;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MapAdapter<K, V> extends XmlAdapter<Adapter<K, V>, Map<K, V>> {

    @Override
    public Map<K, V> unmarshal(Adapter<K, V> v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<K, V>();
        for (MyEntry<K, V> mapEntryType : v.getEntries()) {
            map.put(rUnmarshal(mapEntryType.getKey()), rUnmarshal(mapEntryType.getValue()));
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public Adapter<K, V> marshal(Map<K, V> v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Adapter<K, V>(v);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected static <T> T rUnmarshal(T obj) throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Adapter) {
            return (T) new MapAdapter<>().unmarshal((Adapter<Object, Object>) obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected static <T> T rMarshal(T obj) throws Exception {
        if (obj instanceof Map) {
            return (T) new MapAdapter<>().marshal((Map<Object, Object>) obj);
        }
        return obj;
    }

}

@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
final class Adapter<K, V> {

    @XmlElement
    protected List<MyEntry<K, V>> fEntries = new LinkedList<MyEntry<K, V>>();

    // needed for JAXB
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Adapter() {
    }

    public Adapter(Map<K, V> original) throws Exception {
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : original.entrySet()) {
            this.fEntries.add(new MyEntry<K, V>(entry));
        }
    }

    public List<MyEntry<K, V>> getEntries() {
        return this.fEntries;
    }

}

@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
final class MyEntry<K, V> {

    @XmlElement
    protected K fKey;

    @XmlElement
    protected V fValue;

    // needed for JAXB
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MyEntry() {
    }

    public MyEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> original) throws Exception {
        this.fKey = MapAdapter.rMarshal(original.getKey());
        this.fValue = MapAdapter.rMarshal(original.getValue());
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return this.fKey;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return this.fValue;
    }

}
```