# Cannot marshal map with JAXB owing to: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

In creating a JAX-WS webservice I'm having problems marshaling a `java.util.Map` to XML with JAXB (Java version 1.6.0_26). **The Map in question is a raw type** and this cannot be changed. The map keys are likely to be Strings at run-time but the **values can and will be other objects including other maps and lists**.

It seems most approaches (like [this one](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.com/2012/08/jaxb-annotation-summary-advanced-topics_9.html) or [this one](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.fr/2011/12/java-tip-of-day-generic-jaxb-map-v.html)) for marshaling raw type maps with JAXB, generally recommend converting the map into a more JAXB-friendly structure using an `XmlAdapter` so that it can be marshaled easily thereafter. I've tried to follow this approach but I cannot get away from this error:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
```

### More information

In the recommended approach, the pattern for the `XmlAdapter` always goes like this:

1. You must create a JAXB-friendly class that will be a container - called `MyMap` or `AdapterMap` or similar - and it should have a `List` as a field.
2. The list property of `MyMap` looks like this:

   `List<Entry<K, V>> list = new ArrayList<Entry<K, V>>();`
3. The `Entry` class encapsulates the key `K` and the value `V` pair and looks basically like this:

   ```
   @XmlRootElement
   public class Entry<K, V> {

       @XmlElement
       private K key;

       @XmlElement
       private V value;

       ...
   }
   ```
4. The `XmlAdapter` you write will convert the `java.util.Map` into `MyMap` in the `marshal` method and do the reverse in the `unmarshal` method.

I cannot determine precisely where the problem is but I believe JAXB cannot marshal the `K key` property when the type `java.lang.String` (and probably other types). If the type was explicitly declared as `String` instead of `K` then I'm certain it would work but it's not something I can assume and in any case I could not do the same for `V`, which could be absolutely anything.

Incidentally, since I know that the map I need to marshal and unmarshal will contain other (nested) maps, I found what looks to be a [neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326561/jaxb-marshall-a-map-structure-of-generic-type) using a "RecursiveMapAdapter" but this again results in the same issue.

```
Caused By: com.sun.istack.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:248)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(LeafBeanInfoImpl.java:137)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:114)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:699)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:699)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:168)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:699)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:593)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayReferenceNodeProperty.java:114)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:328)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:699)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:699)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:127)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:316)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:72)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:315)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:244)
        at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:75)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:539)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:233)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:168)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:112)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
        at $Proxy202.doTheWebServiceCall(Unknown Source)
```